# In Rails 5, how access cookies method in a model or helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

How does one access cookies inside a Rails model or helper?

Trying to dry up some controller methods, I am trying to move multiple controller calls to cookies() into application_helper.rb and/or a model.

What **doesn't** work in application_helper.rb:

```
cookies[:foo]
ActionDispatch::Cookies.cookies[:foo]
ActionController.cookies[:foo]
ActionDispatch::Cookies::ChainedCookieJars.cookie[:foo]
```

All of which result in undefined method 'cookies'

Note: Well-meaning answers that simply regurgitate MVC dogma are mis-placed here... I've architected long enough (decades) to know when coloring outside the MVC lines (if possible) is the better route. But the precise syntax eludes me even after digging through Rails source. This question is prompted by a somewhat complex situation related to, among other things, inconsistent browser handling of cookies in cross-domain, ajax environment that sometimes includes local files (for which Chrome declines to manage cookies).

Answer (score 8):

It's not a good idea :) Models are classes, and they shouldn't be aware of what is happening on a web level, and that's why `cookies` method is implemented in `ActionController`, but there's no such implementation in `ActionModel` or `ActionHelper`. If you need a cookie value in a model, pass a value from a controller then. This is how it should be done.

Comment: So where would YOU place the code cookies[:foo] == "somevalue" that occurs 20 times in 3 different controller and 5 or 6 different views?

Comment: @jpwynn if the same part of code "occurs 20 times in 3 different controller and 5 or 6 different views", perhaps your code smells, and you're doing something wrong. If I saw your code I would give an advice how to refactor it. You can always implement a service, or even singleton service to do this dirty work. Believe me, there is a way, and people, who implemented `cookies` method only in `ActionController`, are not stupid and didn't do this occasionally. And down-vote is for wrong answers. You down-voted this just because you don't know how to make your implementation better.

Comment: Agreed - models are outside web requests.  @jpwynn - try to add a before filter that calls a common method or helper that does what you need.

Comment: My question is simple and direct. If you don't care to answer it, or don't know the answer, please ignore it. Sawrds please note I did ask about putting it in application_helper which (from my examples of what didn't work) is clearly my first choice.. Vasily the downvote is because your answer does not answer the question... it did not ask IF you think it's a good idea, it asks HOW to do it. Now, had you added a comment to my question "bad idea" i would not downvote that. But a non-answer gets a downvote.

Comment: @jpwynn Okay, your question gets a downvote then, because you ask about not proper way of programming in a situation when it can be done in a proper way, and don't want to listen to other people, and your question will also confuse newbies in rails, because they will think it's okay to use cookies everywhere. And here's the direct answer: no way. You are doing it wrong, and the only way to access cookies without hacks or patches is to pass them from classes which are inherited from `ActionController`, because that is how it **MUST** be done.

Comment: Vasily, people used to express the exact same charmingly devoted dogma about accessing view helpers in controllers and SO was full of answers just like yours that preached. But now Rails 5 supports it directly. You know why? Because sometimes it makes sense. Just like my question does. If it's not possible (today) so be it. But the question stands.

Comment: @jpwynn it wasn't that hard to use a helper method in a controller. And each time I wanted to use a helper method in a controller, I realized there's another, much more beautiful way. More than 4 years of commercial development – never used helper in a controller.

Answer (score 1):

As @Vasili mentioned, `cookies` is only available in controllers. But if you want to access `cookies` in helpers or models, just pass it as an argument, for example:

helper example:

```rb
module ApplicationHelper
  def some_helper(given_cookies)
    given_cookies[:foo] = 'bar'
  end
end
```

In view:

```
<%= some_helper(cookies) %>
```