# Rails: Access cookies in a class in a helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

I have a ruby class in a rails helper and **inside** that class I cannot access the ActiveController cookies method. I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43150357/in-rails-5-how-access-cookies-method-in-a-model-or-helper) and it doesn't solve my problem and I'm not doing what that guy is since my ruby class is in the scope of the controller and is only ever called by it. What's the best way to get rid of the

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `cookies` for #<CartHelper::CartObject:...>):

app/helpers/cart_helper.rb:##:in `save`
app/helpers/cart_helper.rb:##:in `add_product`
app/controllers/cart_controller.rb:##:in `add`
```

in my helper? (I'm also open to suggestions on how to make this more Ruby-y approach wise)

```
module CartHelper
  class CartObject
    def load (cart)
      # converts from json
    end
    private def save
      cookies.signed.permanent[:cart] = dump
    end
    private def dump
      # converts to json
    end

    def add_product (product)
      # ...
      save
    end
    def remove_product (product)
      # ...
      save
    end
  end
  def get_cart
    return CartObject.new if cookies.signed.permanent[:cart].nil?
    CartObject.load(cookies.signed.permanent[:cart])
  end
end
```

and `CartHelper` is included in the application controller of course

```
class CartController < ApplicationController\
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: [:add]
  def view
    cart = get_cart
    @products = cart.products
  end
  def add # only by ajax
    cart = get_cart
    cart.add_product(Oj.strict_load(params[:product]))
    head 200
  end
  def remove
    cart = get_cart
    cart.remove_product(params['rem'])
    flash['success'] = 'Product removed.'
    redirect_to '/cart'
  end
end
```

Comment: Why not just pass the cookies from the contoller

Comment: That reverts me to where I was before with just doing it all in a helper anyway, which is seeming like the solution but I'd love to have all of the saving and loading in this class.